# RecordSet and Ms Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a query that has CustID with mutiple Business affiliated with the CustID. I can't use Dlookup because it only returns one variable. I want to show on a form that for this custID, here are all the businesses it's affiliated it. I want the Businesses to show up into a field (business) in another table on the form.

I started out by this

```
Public Sub OpenRecordset()


Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Q:businesses")
Do While Not rs.EOF
T:Custinfo!business = NAME (I am lost in between on how to identify the custid and place the businesses into the table field as a Dlookup)

rs.movenext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close


End Sub
```

I keep looking at other examples but can't seem to tie together where the dlookup replacement will take place and how will you have to put this on a form as a datasheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a DLookup.  You could do one of two things:

1)  Use a listbox and set the recordsource equal to your query (assuming Q:businesses has been appropriately defined to give the businesses as a result)

2)  Still need your query to be appropriate, but you could create a string with all of the businesses in it:

```
Public Sub OpenRecordset()


Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim StrBusinesses As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryBusinesses")
If rs.EOF and rs.BOF Then
    MsgBox("No businesses exist for this Customer")
    Exit Sub 'Or do whatever else you want if there are no matches
Else
    rs.MoveFirst
End If
StrBusinesses = ""
Do While Not rs.EOF
    StrBusinesses = StrBusinesses & rs!Business & ", "
    rs.movenext
Loop

rs.Close
StrBusinesses = Left(StrBusinesses, Len(StrBusinesses) - 2)
Forms!MyForm.MyField = StrBusinesses 'Set the field equal to the string here
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close


End Sub
```

Of course this assumes that the query "Q:Business" is defined to get the appropriate info such as:

```
SELECT custID, business FROM tblBusinesses WHERE custID = X
```

where "X" is the custID you are looking for.

If you need to set the query dynamically, you will need to set a querydef.

EDIT to include querydef code***********************
Also changed the name of the query to "qryBusinesses" in the code above and below as I'm not sure whether you can make a query with a colon in it.

To set the querydef, put this at the beginning of the code:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryBusinesses")
qdf.SQL = "SELECT custID, business FROM tblBusinesses" _
         & " WHERE custID = " & Forms!MyForm.CustID 'replace with actual form and field
```

This assumes that i) qryBusinesses exists already,
                  ii) custID is a number field

EDIT**************
If you define the query to look at the form itself, you would not need to set the sql, so if the query were defined (either in VBA or through the query wizard) as:
    qdf.sql = "SELECT custID, business FROM tblBusinesses" _
         & " WHERE custID = Forms!MyForm.CustID"

then you would not need to redefine the sql.  However, it is a bit more dynamic to put the custID into the qdf itself as it is easier to debug any issues as you can see the exact sql that is being run in the original method.

Comment: Thank you, If you put these fields on a form, can you pull them into a report as well? Also, can we put in the Query that Where CustID = ["Form name"]?

Comment: You can put that in the query as long as you make the query dynamically.  I'll add an edit to show how to do so.

Comment: Thank you OpiesDad, after I put this into a module, how do I actually get this to show in a form? Do I just create a textbox and bound it to the event with on Click?

Comment: That's what this line does "Forms!MyForm.MyField = StrBusinesses"  You need to replace "MyForm" and "MyField" with the relevant form and field that you want.  Just make a text box on the form to hold it.  Otherwise, if you use option1, then you will already have a listbox.  Then you just set the listbox.recordsource equal to the query that you made and it will contain the needed info.

Comment: Also, for the qd.SQL, can I write a sql query code that has multiple left joins?  Because the FROM tblebusinesses is actually pulling from multiple tables. @opiesdad

Comment: okay let me lookinto a list box and try both. I am trying to learn recordsets for my db, so I decided to go the harder route. Hopefully I can get both to work.

Comment: You can do whatever SQL you want.  It should have been "qdf.sql" instead of "qd.sql".  I updated it in the answer.  Now that I think about it, you can actually change the openrecordset line towards the beginning to "set rs = qdf.openrecordset" and get rid of the db line above it if you're working with qdfs anyways.

Comment: while I'm trying to learn record sets and module, Do you think you can explain a little bit about how the text box will list the multiple businesses? Maybe I'm thinking that a text box can only show one variable but with this record set, it has the capability to show a list?

Comment: Okay, another question for querydef is why do I have to designate my qdf as well as a qdf.sql, If I have the qrybusiness already?  I want to make sure I understand this while I'm building it. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: The first line "Set qdf = ....." is setting the querydef object to the query that you already have, named qrybusiness.  The second line "qdf.sql = ..." is setting the query to whatever SQL you put there.  If qrybusiness already has the appropriate sql in it, you wouldn't need to redefine the query.  However, if you want to dynamically change the sql then you need to do this.

Comment: okay, @opiesdad, I am working on it right now. Hope you don't mind if I have more quesitons

Comment: I was having it work for a while, but now I keep getting an error at the Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset, too few paraameters. expected 2 at 3061. No matter what i try to do what I was getting it to show it keeps giving me that error. @opiesdad

Comment: actually its back to normal and works good. The next thing I have is that it says that the buisness field could refer to more than one table listed in the from sql clause but it isn't anywhere else.

Comment: I'd need to see the sql to fix it.  Or just clearly define the business field in the sql:  SELECT businesstable.businessfield

Comment: So My currentdb.querydefs("Qoff") has a business as well as my qdf.sql, I think that is the problem. Even when I added the buisnesstable.businessfield, I go back to the error that says too few parameters, when I pick debug, I get the Set rs =qdf.openRecordset highlight. Then, when I delete the sql code, I still get the too few paramaters issues. Is there a reason why it keeps doing that?  My sql code is as following with the copied relationships from access: @opiesdad

Comment: qdf.SQL = "SELECT custID, business FROM ('list of joined tables copied from access" _
         & " WHERE custID = " & Forms!MyForm.CustID

Comment: That's the line of code that sets the sql.  Did you replace the "Forms!MyForm.CustID" with your textbox that contains the custID on your form?  You need to put the name of your form and field in here....

Comment: do I need to clear something to get that error to go away? I did change the forms, I just didn't include it in here. When I don't include the qdf.sql = sql code, everything works except that it imports every single buisness from "qryBusinesses" as expected. then I add it and it messes up, then i remove it and still get the too few parameters error. For some reason the most important part of only grabing the the buisness affilated with the custID qdf.sql won't recognize that I am only trying to grab the businesses with Forms!MyForm.CustID = custID.

Comment: Debug Print qdf.sql when the error occurs then copy the sql into an access query and try to run it.  You can probably get more useful error messages this way and fix the sql.  Maybe the custID isn't getting put in there properly or something else is happening.